# Checking existed value in array of nested object before update in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

This is my cart model:

```
const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "userSchema",
    },
    cart: [
        {
            product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "productSchema" },
            amount: { type: Number, require: true, min: 0 },
            price: { type: Number, min: 0 },
        },
    ],
    totalPrice: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        default: 0,
    },
});
```

I would like to check cart.product before update it, pushes new item if not exist else increment amount with item
I'm trying this way test pushing first but it's not working properly

```
router.put("/add-to-cart", authenticateToken, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const productInfo = await productSchema.findById(req.body.id);
        const filter = {
            $and: [{ user: req.user }, { "cart.product": { $nin: [req.body.id] } }],
        };
        const options = { upsert: true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true };
        const update = {
            $push: {
                cart: {
                    product: req.body.id,
                    amount: req.body.amount,
                    price: req.body.amount * productInfo.productPrice,
                },
            },
        };
        await cartSchema.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options);
        return res.status(201).send({ status: true });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: err });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works fine, maybe is because of your transition of Id and objectId

```
db.collection.update({
  $and: [
    {
      user: "1"
    },
    {
      "cart.product": {
        $nin: [
          "1"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  
},
{
  $push: {
    cart: {
      product: "1",
      amount: 1,
      price: 10
    }
  }
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p_GgXy63TiB)